# How to use WSO2 MB in WSO2 ESB

Tags: web-applications, wso2, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I've tried using **WSO2 Message Broker** individually,it works well and fine.

Actually, I've created two separate Java Application which acts as sender and receiver. Both the applications uses amqp connection string to initiate the connection. Used Apache Ant server to build the application.

Now I want to integrate the Message Broker with the WSO2 ESB.

**Suggest me the best way to use the Message Broker in my Web application using the ESB**.

I get confused with sometimes,

**confusion 1**: *Difference between Message Store and Message Broker*.

**confusion 2**: *Does the Web Application requires connection string to use message broker*

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will be better if you can understand basic concepts of Message Broker.

Message broker is a simply handle messaging functionalities. In WSO2 MB, we use amqp as the protocol.

**Confusion 01**: Message store in ESB is a place where you use to store messages. In ESB you can configure store as in memory, jms etc. Through that, store qualities will be differ. (Ex: In memory messages deleted after server restart)

While configuring jms message store, we can use message broker. Then Message broker queue can be used as store. In here we create an queue and point it as message store. So message will be stored in that queue.

**Confusion 02**: While you connecting to message broker, you should create the connection as described in documentation.

You can refer documentation regarding MB/ESB integration: https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/Integrating+WSO2+ESB
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Configure+with+WSO2+Message+Broker

Comment: Thanks for clearing my confusion.... but how can i use the message broker through ESB. I've created the connection for publishing, using the connection string through MB. I want to do it after integration in ESB

Comment: You have to add MB client libraries in to ESB. ($Home/repository/components/lib) and add relevant configs in to axis2.xml ($Home/repository/conf/axis2/). Please refer documentation regarding steps.